# How to make a file open by default with tkinter app?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I made a tkinter app for displaying images, and I was wondering if there's a way to make an image open by default with this app
At the moment if I try that, I get an error for some non declared icon file (this is the icon that appears near the name of the app at the top)
There's no real goal behin this Gui, I'm just experimenting and learning.

Thanks

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you are having, and include the exact error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: This is the error
cx_Freeze:Python error in main script

Traceback:
File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1871, in wm_iconbitmap return self.tk.call('wm','iconbitmap',self._w,bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "logo.ico" not defined

Comment: for a code example the one that @Ayush Raj provided is basically the same you can use it as reference

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
my_img = []
def FileImport():
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    my_img.clear()
    my_img.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file)))
    label1.config(image=my_img[0])


root= tk.Tk()
root.title('Main')
root.geometry('400x400')
label = tk.Label(root, text = "Browse", fg="purple")
label.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text='See Image',fg="blue", command=FileImport)
button.pack()
my_img.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(your_first_image)))
label1 = tk.Label(root, image = my_img[0])
label1.pack(pady= 50)

root.mainloop()
```

When you run this:

[image: Output]

After you tap to see different image from computer:
[image: After Browsing image]

Hope It helps!

Comment: This is basically the same as mine. It still generates the same traceback error, when I open an image from outside the app. It works when I open it from within the app though

Comment: This is the error cx_Freeze:Python error in main script Traceback: File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1871, in wm_iconbitmap return self.tk.call('wm','iconbitmap',self._w,bitmap) _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "logo.ico" not defined

Comment: As for the code it's the same as your code. I tried yours and the same error occured

Comment: It's workingfor me. Are you sure my code is as like yours ?

Comment: It works if I open the image from within the app. What's not working is opening the image with the app when I double click on an image in a folder(without launching the app)